# How to change textframe creation order in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, javascript

I am writing a script for Indesign. In that script I am taking the contents of the text frames and save them to a database. Till here my script works. However when looping between text frames script uses creation order. I want to save to database in question order.

Here is my script:

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;var frameList = myDocument.textFrames;
for (var i = 0; i < frameList.length; i++){ 
    var txt=frameList[i].contents;
    SaveToDB(txt);
}
```

So is there a way to change creation order of textframes

[image: Indesign I'm working with]

Comment: The only way to 'change' creation order is to delete all text frames and then re-create them in the correct order. Consider using the question number in the frame instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to change the "creation order", you simply need to rearrange the text frames in the Layers panel. The text frame at the lowest position in the stack will be treated as if it were created first, and the one at the highest position as if it were created last.

However, I know of no way to change this stack order via script (if somebody knows one, I would be curious to hear it).

So your choices are to either manually rearranging this stack order in the Layers panel and then run your script or to do what Jongware said, to sort it by the question numbers.